# Iterating over an array of objects and stack a Chart JS Bar?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I got the following json object from my backend that I wish to populate in a stacked chart using Chart JS

```
[
    {
        "user": {
            "username": "erik",
            "first_name": "erik",
            "email": "erik@admin.com"
        },
        "hours": {
            "day_1": 13.0,
            "day_2": 14.0,
            "day_3": 9.0,
            "day_4": 8.0,
            "day_5": 8.0,
            "day_6": 3.0,
            "day_7": null
        },
        "project": 21,
        "year": 2020,
        "week": 37
    },
    {
        "user": {
            "username": "mega",
            "first_name": "boy",
            "email": "mega@boy.com"
        },
        "hours": {
            "day_1": 5.0,
            "day_2": 10.0,
            "day_3": 8.0,
            "day_4": 8.0,
            "day_5": null,
            "day_6": null,
            "day_7": null
        },
        "project": 21,
        "year": 2020,
        "week": 37
    }
]
```

My `..data.labels` in Chart JS is manually added as `["Mon", "Tues", "Wed".... ,"Sun"]` which corresponds to each day - now I just need to properly populate each `day` with the right value

Any particular tips on how to iterate over this dataset and populate the Chart JS' `....data.datasets[N].data` part, as seen here:

```
            timesheetChartData: {
                type: 'bar',
                data: {
                    labels: ['Mon', 'Tues', 'Wed', 'Thurs', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'],
                    datasets: [ 
                        { 
                            label: 'Weekly Summary',
                            data: [], // array of what I assume will be stacked bars?
                            backgroundColor: "#2ecc71",
                            borderWidth: 1
                        },
                    ]
                },
                options: {
                    responsive: true,
                    lineTension: 1,
                    scales: {
                        yAxes: [{
                            ticks: {
                                beginAtZero: true,
                                padding: 25,
                            }
                        }],
                    }
                }
            },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your backend data present in an array named `baseData`, you could use the [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) methods in order to generate the `datasets` as follows:

```
const colors = ['green', 'red'];
const datasets = baseData.map((o, i) => ({
  label: o.user.username,
  data: Object.values(o.hours),
  backgroundColor: colors[i]
}));
```

Please take a look at your amended code below:

```js
const baseData = [{
    "user": {
      "username": "erik",
      "first_name": "erik",
      "email": "erik@admin.com"
    },
    "hours": {
      "day_1": 13.0,
      "day_2": 14.0,
      "day_3": 9.0,
      "day_4": 8.0,
      "day_5": 8.0,
      "day_6": 3.0,
      "day_7": null
    },
    "project": 21,
    "year": 2020,
    "week": 37
  },
  {
    "user": {
      "username": "mega",
      "first_name": "boy",
      "email": "mega@boy.com"
    },
    "hours": {
      "day_1": 5.0,
      "day_2": 10.0,
      "day_3": 8.0,
      "day_4": 8.0,
      "day_5": null,
      "day_6": null,
      "day_7": null
    },
    "project": 21,
    "year": 2020,
    "week": 37
  }
];

const colors = ['green', 'red'];
const datasets = baseData.map((o, i) => ({
  label: o.user.username,
  data: Object.values(o.hours),
  backgroundColor: colors[i]
}));

new Chart('canvas', {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ['Mon', 'Tues', 'Wed', 'Thurs', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'],
    datasets: datasets
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'Weekly Summary'
    },
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        stacked: true,
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }],
      xAxes: [{
        stacked: true
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```